# Create a new record in data frame if column value has more than one value

Tags: pandas

I have a df:

```
        author                    text                 symbols
0  IAMLLUCIANA        ZERO are legends                ['ZERO']
1  IAMLLUCIANA        I love this game                 ['ERN']
2  IAMLLUCIANA           This is great                ['ZERO']
3  IAMLLUCIANA  Ricky knows about this          ['HTR', 'ZCX']
4  IAMLLUCIANA        You CANNOT match               ['BONDLY']
5  IAMLLUCIANA        I love this game    ['ERN', 'HTR', 'ZCX']
```

Where the symbols column has more than one symbol in a record (for example record 3 has two symbols (HTR and ZCX).  Is it possible to create a separate record for each so my desired output would look like:

```
        author                    text          symbols
0  IAMLLUCIANA        ZERO are legends          ['ZERO']
1  IAMLLUCIANA        I love this game           ['ERN']
2  IAMLLUCIANA           This is great          ['ZERO']
3  IAMLLUCIANA  Ricky knows about this           ['HTR']
4  IAMLLUCIANA  Ricky knows about this           ['ZCX']
5  IAMLLUCIANA        You CANNOT match        ['BONDLY']
6  IAMLLUCIANA        I love this game           ['ERN']
7  IAMLLUCIANA        I love this game           ['HTR']
8  IAMLLUCIANA        I love this game           ['ZCX']
```

Comment: `df.explode('symbols')` ??

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'symbols'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['IAMLLUCIANA', 'IAMLLUCIANA', 'IAMLLUCIANA', 'IAMLLUCIANA', 'IAMLLUCIANA', 'IAMLLUCIANA'], 
...                      'text': ['ZERO are legends', 'I love this game', 'This is great', 'Ricky knows about this', 'You CANNOT match', 'I love this game'], 
...                      'symbols': ["['ZERO']", "['ERN']", "['ZERO']", "['HTR', 'ZCX']", "['BONDLY']", "['ERN', 'HTR', 'ZCX']"]}, 
...                     index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
>>> df_1
    author          text                    symbols
0   IAMLLUCIANA     ZERO are legends        ['ZERO']
1   IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN']
2   IAMLLUCIANA     This is great           ['ZERO']
3   IAMLLUCIANA     Ricky knows about this  ['HTR', 'ZCX']
4   IAMLLUCIANA     You CANNOT match        ['BONDLY']
5   IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN', 'HTR', 'ZCX']
```

We add missing brackets in the `list` :

```py
>>> df_1['symbols'] = df_1['symbols'].str.replace(", ",'],[')
>>> df_1
    author          text                    symbols
0   IAMLLUCIANA     ZERO are legends        ['ZERO']
1   IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN']
2   IAMLLUCIANA     This is great           ['ZERO']
3   IAMLLUCIANA     Ricky knows about this  ['HTR'],['ZCX']
4   IAMLLUCIANA     You CANNOT match        ['BONDLY']
5   IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN'],['HTR'],['ZCX']
```

We build a new `DataFrame` where we `stack` the `list` elements :

```py
>>> df_2 = df_1['symbols'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().to_frame().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
>>> df_2 = df_2.rename(columns={0: 'all_symbol'})
>>> df_2
    level_0     all_symbol
0   0           ['ZERO']
1   1           ['ERN']
2   2           ['ZERO']
3   3           ['HTR']
4   3           ['ZCX']
5   4           ['BONDLY']
6   5           ['ERN']
7   5           ['HTR']
8   5           ['ZCX']
```

Then we `merge` the result with the first `DataFrame` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df = pd.merge(df_2,
...               df_1,
...               how='left',
...               left_on=['level_0'],
...               right_index=True)  
>>> df.drop('level_0', axis=1)
    all_symbol  author          text                    symbols
0   ['ZERO']    IAMLLUCIANA     ZERO are legends        ['ZERO']
1   ['ERN']     IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN']
2   ['ZERO']    IAMLLUCIANA     This is great           ['ZERO']
3   ['HTR']     IAMLLUCIANA     Ricky knows about this  ['HTR'],['ZCX']
4   ['ZCX']     IAMLLUCIANA     Ricky knows about this  ['HTR'],['ZCX']
5   ['BONDLY']  IAMLLUCIANA     You CANNOT match        ['BONDLY']
6   ['ERN']     IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN'],['HTR'],['ZCX']
7   ['HTR']     IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN'],['HTR'],['ZCX']
8   ['ZCX']     IAMLLUCIANA     I love this game        ['ERN'],['HTR'],['ZCX']
```